# Как по ViewModel найти ее контрол?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

В `SelectedItem` приходит `Vm` из которой контрол достает данные. Но как мне получить сам контрол, а не его `Vm`?

```
 private void AssociatedObject_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItem;
            var module = selectedItem as ModuleVm;
            if (module != null)
            {
                //сделать IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Кстати, вместо двойного `if` можно сразу написать `this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItem as ModuleVm`. Если, конечно, у вас там еще нет дополнительной логики после второго `if`.

Comment: @andreycha, Да, действительно так.

Comment: Никак, вам это и не должно быть нужно. Drag-and-drop-ом должен заниматься UI, а не VM.

Comment: @VladD, Так уж сложилось что у нас `Drag-n-Drop`-ом занимается `VM`. И мне очень нужно как-то выкрутиться из этой ситуации. Может есть какой-то способ?

Comment: @Lightness: Перебрать все контролы, посмотреть на их DataContext, и построить отображение VM в контрол? В качестве грубого хака сойдёт. А какого типа ваши контролы? Они случайно не элементы ListView или чего-то такого?

Comment: @VladD, они элементы TreeView

Comment: @Lightness: Тогда вам, возможно, покатит `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`? http://stackoverflow.com/q/616948/276994

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо за варианты, я как проверю отпишусь.

Comment: @VladD,  Проканал `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`! :)

Comment: @Lightness: Отлично, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего должно быть получить `TreeViewItem` по VM отдельного элемента так:

```
(TreeViewItem)treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(vm)
```

Отталкиваясь от него, можно либо найти поиском в глубину `ItemTemplate`, или работать с контейнером непосредственно.